# element.all(locator).first() vs element(locator) with warning?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, testing, protractor

During the build process of an application I'm working on, I have been getting warnings about `element(locator)` returning more than one result, with the first matching element being returned.

Would the build process speed up if I were to do `element.all(locator).first()`?

Comment: maybe you should find a better locator, so you are safe if the page ordering changes.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/element.js#L247), `first()` is basically calling `get(0)` on a `ElementArrayFinder`. `get(index)` would not make protractor search for a single element at a specified index, instead - protractor would first ask the webdriver *find all of the elements matching a locator and only then retrieve an element at a specified index*. There is no special handling or performance improvement for the first element at the 0 index.